# HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 BAD REQUEST when service return []

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, web-services

I'm running a service and it works perfectly when it returns some entidade. But when it doesn't find any, I get the following error:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 BAD REQUEST: [{
***"entidades": []***,
"saida": "" rua bandeirantes, 1578 - bairro: cent... (19970 bytes)]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:818)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:467)
at br.mp.mpf.cened01.cargaIaRJ.RJServico.executarServico(RJServico.java:953)
at br.mp.mpf.cened01.cargaIaRJ.RJServico.executarServicoByPagina(RJServico.java:857)
at br.mp.mpf.cened01.cargaIaRJ.RJServico.executarComPaginacao(RJServico.java:752)
at br.mp.mpf.cened01.cargaIaRJ.RJApplication.lambda$0(RJApplication.java:52)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
at br.mp.mpf.cened01.cargaIaRJ.RJApplication.main(RJApplication.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

```
    private RetornoServicoDto executarServico(String sentenca) 
            throws Exception {
        RetornoServicoDto retornoServico = new RetornoServicoDto();

        final String sentencaOri = sentenca;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       final Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>> iterator = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().iterator();
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final HttpMessageConverter<?> converter = iterator.next();
          if (converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
            iterator.remove();
          }       
       }
       restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        try {         
            ResponseEntity<RetornoServicoDto> responseEntity = 
                    restTemplate.postForEntity(Constantes.SERVICO_URL,
                            sentencaOri, RetornoServicoDto.class);

            retornoServico = responseEntity.getBody();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retornoServico;
    }  

@Data
public class RetornoServicoDto {    
    private List<EntidadeDto> entidades; 
    private String saida;
    private String status;  
} 

@Data
public class EntidadeDto {
    private String entidade;
    private int id;
    private PosicaoDto posicao;
    private String texto;
}
```

What to do to work even when the entities list returns []?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see from your log, your response object starts with an "[{..." so probably your server side is returning an list of RetornoServicoDto, not a single object that what you are asking the request for, since your problem is a bad request, would be great to see the service side that process the request to understand better.